# PearsonChiSquareTest for count/frequency data?

Tags: fitting, distributions, probability-or-statistics

I read with interest a previous question on the `PearsonChiSquareTest` from a few years ago, and one answer was very helpful:

[Performing a chi-square goodness of fit test](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5590/37421)

Have there been any updates since 2012 for testing counts/frequency data? Although easy to implement manually, I do not understand why testing with the following example data (two 'distributions' of counts?) produces different results to those computed manually:

```
real = {331, 155, 337, 302, 86}
expected = {650.797, 118.261, 325.545, 109.397, 6.99883}
```

With `PearsonChiSquareTest[real,expected]` the test statistic is only 1.6, and a high p-value. But manually (or using MATLAB or SPSS) the test gives 1400 and a very small p-value (<0.001). It also confusingly gives degrees of freedom as 3  with the `PearsonChiSquareTest`. Any suggestions/clarification?

Comment: The documentation for `PearsonChiSquareTest` states that continuous distributions are being compared.  When data is supplied, it is in the form of actual sample values and not counts.  You need a different test for what is likely observed counts from a multinomial distribution.  (I'm more than a bit surprised that the expected counts are exactly integers - or should the variables be named `real1` and `real2` ?.)

Comment: You are right, the expected counts are not integers, I had just rounded them before copy/paste. That makes sense about the types of distributions being tested, I did not think about it in that way.

Comment: If your model (with the data that results in the expected values) can be cast as a generalized linear model, then `GeneralizedLinearModelFit` would work for you.  But you'd need to give more information about your model, data, and how you obtained the expected values.